# How to access specific row from CSV with Jekyll?

Tags: csv, jekyll

I am using Jekyll [2.5.3] to build a prototype and need to access a specific rows from a file in `_data` in my layouts.

In file `_data/badges.csv` I have:

```
name, image_url
Heat, http://pathtoimage.com/image-1.png
Water, http://pathtoimage.com/image-2.png
Zoning, http://pathtoimage.com/image-3.png
...
```

In `_layout/page.html` I am trying to access the `Zoning` row from `badges.csv` by passing a value to `site.data` like so:

```
{% assign badge = site.data.badges.name["Zoning"] %}
{{ badge.image_url }}
```

Eventually I will make `["Zoning"]` a page variable to load specific badges based on the page.

I've tried `[Zoning]`, `['Zoning']`, `["Zoning"]`. None of these output any data and do not throw an error during `jekyll build`.

How can I access a specific row from the CSV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe CSV files are treated as arrays instead of maps. If you want to find a specific entry in a CSV you could do something like this:

```
{% for badge in site.data.badges %}
  {% if badge.name == "Zoning" %}
    {{ badge.image_url }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You could then move that into `_includes` and pass an argument to reuse the functionality:

**_includes/badge-url.html**

```
{% for badge in site.data.badges %}
  {% if badge.name == include.name %}
    {{ badge.image_url }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Including Zoning**

```
{% include badge-url.html name="Zoning" %}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. And you are correct about CSVs outputting arrays not maps. Thanks a ton!

Comment: While this works like a charm, I am wondering how to do it without a for loop. In case of large data files this will take a long time to loop each time you want to retrieve some data.

Comment: @BrandonStephens do you know if its possible to change the default array from csv to a map instead?

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll 4.2 introduced the `find` [liquid tag](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) which is helpful for this.

For example, with a CSV file at `_data/people.csv` with a similar format as:

```
name, slug, title
Jane Doe, jane-doe, VP of Stuff
```

You can do this:

```
{% assign person = site.data.people | find:"slug","jane-doe" %}
{{ person.name }}
```

Which will print out their name from the CSV.